# Mixing fanout and direct exchanges with AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have two kinds of workers for a same event.

I would like a message be dispatched to only one among some of my workers (like "direct" exchanges). But the other workers should all process the message (like fanout).

It's a bit hard to explain but the idea is here. And maybe the following schema will help you to understand what I would like.

[image: Architecture I would like to have]

Do you have a solution?

Kind regards,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have "type-1" as worker where only a single worker work on an item  while "type-2" can be treated as multiple  handlers (like log-handlers) where all should accept the event.

If i'm right , then you might be able to chain two queues (exchanges) . 
exchange1 - fanout -  all the "type-2" (loggers) will wait here so they will all get the event
exchange2 - direct - all your "type-1" will wait here so only one will get the event

the trick - you need to make sure that you have a consumer listening on "exchange1" that will also publish to "exchange2".

Comment: Hey Pauwelyn, I actually think that it answers the question but i definitely get your point. thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

your best option is to use routing keys with multiple bindings between your exchange and your queues.

i would recommend either direct or topic exchange for this, but not fanout.

to model your example image above, your configuration would look like this:

```
| exchange | routing key | queue   |
|----------|-------------|---------|
| some.ex  | type.1      | queue.1 | 
| some.ex  | type.1      | queue.2 | 
| some.ex  | type.1      | queue.3 | 
| some.ex  | type.2      | queue.4 | 
| some.ex  | type.2      | queue.5 |
```

basically, you need to have a routing key per queue and a queue per worker.

---

you may want to read up a bit more on exchanges, queues and bindings, to get a better understanding of when they would be used. i have a few ebooks that cover this (along with other RMQ usage scenarios) at https://leanpub.com/u/derickbailey